# Debugging of object of DOMXPath and DOMDocument

Tags: php, domxpath

We use echo or `print_r` to get value of variables while debugging PHP code.

But, object of DOMXPath or DOMDocument are not captured in `echo` or `print_r`.

How to get values from above objects while debugging PHP code?

Comment: You can `var_dump` DOMDocument and DOMXPath instances. But the object's properties wont be dumped like they are with regular objects. So the question should be either "Why are instance members of DOM instances not dumped and how to achieve that"

Comment: An answer depends on what you are looking to get out of "debugging" the objects.  To see the XML use the [`DOMDocument::saveXML`](http://php.net/domdocument.savexml) method (for the document, or nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug:

- [Bug #48527: DOM XML classes do not expose properties to Reflection](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48527)

For some reason, `DOM*` classes do not expose their properties, neither to Reflection, nor to any other function capable of inspecting objects. You'd have to write a custom inspector that collects the properties manually.